# Rupee symbol ( ₹ ) not working in firefox

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, bootstrap-modal

I maintain a currency table in mysql. All the symbols are stored in that table. but i try to print symbol in bootstrap print, all other symbols working fine except ₹  .

### Currency table

[image]

I used this update in our system its worked
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2496898

Our problem is:
Any other solution to solve this problem without system update (codeigniter/jquery).

Its billing software. party based billing, every party mapped with currency.its dynamic currency symbol printing.
[image]

Comment: `£` should be `GBP` not `IMP`

Answer (score 1):

Use Unicode Characters : `&#x20B9;`

Comment: Our table contain 112 symbols.how can i find character set for all  the symbol.Your answer is only for rupee, but i maintain all country currency, how its possible.

Comment: check this out

https://www.toptal.com/designers/htmlarrows/currency/

Answer (score 1):

Use HTML Entities instead of signs.
For INR, use `&#8377;`

Source : [**URL**](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20b9/index.htm)